Android software application that supports machine companion programming
I am looking for an Android software program that supports machine companion programming.
Several of us, have, companions. With these companions, we can tell them things, they may reply to us, and, we may then reply, to the question at hand (getting on with our day, getting engaged with, and, doing, what we have to do).
It is nice to ask our companions the same things, over, and over again, or be told over and over again, the same things.
However, it would be also nice to become aware of these kinds of conversations, and, have them with our phones, when our companions are far away or at work, and, we cannot afford to stress them out (or, get in touch with them, after all, they may want us to get down to doing our tasks independently, and, we may be in need, of the conversation (at crucial moments)).
So, I was wondering, if the interactivity of these companions can be coded into the phone (for example, directly, be m by the conversationsm archiver, achiever, doer, practicer). Who, using this type of exchange, could also become, a planner, a future seer and heart, plan, or action, mixer.
Here is what I was thinking.
So, it would be nice to program a companion (via software to support machine companion programming). Using an arbitrary variable  beaching factor and depth tree, one could program a set dialogue, that works as commands, response, and response upon response giving
You code your commands at the first level, what the other person replies to that at the second level, what responses you may give su the third level to stop the interaction (while, you have told yourself what to get down to doing). Would this be a black-red tree?
At this point, you can return to the first level in the tree and ask your companion something else.
You may even name your companion (to which the interaction is attached as an encoding).
Interactions, encoded, in this standard (set, arranged, way), with each interaction leading to a set response in your mind, activity, and interaction/doing thinking, could, be, potentially, quite complex.
You could even have a hook into ChatGPT if you wanted to have something that required thinking as a response, stimulated, by the conversation content, rather, than by the ask, response, reply pattern.
Here are some sample example interactions:
For example
in the morning one could wake up and ask their smartphone:
"What can I do?"
The smatphone checks the time. It is programmed to respond as following when it sees it is the morning: "-prepare breakfast, -prepare clothes, -clean the floor, -take medication. -Put something on television."
You can tell your smartphone "one at a time".

Prepare breakfast.
I'm doing it
Prepare clothes
Ok. The user codes the app to answer as follows after the user responds with I'm doing it, with a timer (and the user can inspect, edit, and save, all timed interactions).
Did you finish preparing breakfast?
I'm almost done
Done

And so on.
The program can be set to respond with "did you set the table?", after the user responds with "done".
When I tell you "I took my medication", ask me, "what did you do, what did you take in particular?".
When I tell you "I am hungry", tell me "did you do your shopping?".
When I tell you, "what can I do?", if it is 6 in the morning tell me "clean the house".
When asked "Where is the broom?", answer, "in the bathroom closet, at the balcony, or upstairs".
...
Then when you want, you can tell your companion things, and it reacts as programmed, also checking the time and circumstances.
Reason about when you say this, what does your loved one say to you. Then, program, your device accordingly (in, order... to function even when your loved one is not in your whereabouts or is busy doing something or would like you to be independent on your own, reasoning, as if your loved one was there).
..
It could even be, that, after encoding a companion in software, thoughts, may arise (and, thoughts, may be put into effect), and, interactions with the main, real, companion, may become more fluid, rich, and complex or overviewed / overvieeing, leading to more comprehension between the person listening to their companion and their companion.
The stuff, can be, updated.
